# Python numpy mask a range of values

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I have a 2D array called img of size 100x100. I am trying to mask all values bigger than -100 and lesser than 100 as folows.

```
img = np.ma.masked_where(-100 < img < 100, img)
```

However, the above gives me an error saying

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Thanks.

Comment: `1 < a <2` is valid only for scalar Python operations.  It doesn't work with numpy arrays.  Test the masking condition by itself.  You should get a boolean array.  And test things with a small array that you can look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the chained comparisons with NumPy arrays because they use Pythons `and` under the hood.

You have to use `&` or the function equivalents [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) or [`numpy.bitwise_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html).

For example:

```
np.ma.masked_where((-100 < img) & (img < 100), img)
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that `&` and `|` are *bitwise* operators, and **not** *logical* operators. They work fine with boolean arrays, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [masked inside](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_inside.html#numpy.ma.masked_inside), for instance we can mask the value between the 2 and 5 range:

```
import numpy as np 
from numpy import ma 
img = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
imgm = ma.masked_inside(img,2,5)
```